# Table with virtual scroll and flex scroll not rendering rows

Tags: angular, primeng

I am having trouble getting virtual scrolling working on a table using Flex Scroll with  `scrollHeight='flex'`

I have an outer element set with a fixed height like so:

```html
<div style="height: 800px">
    <h5>Virtual Scroll with Preloaded Data (1000 Rows)</h5>
    <p-table
      [columns]="cols"
      [value]="cars"
      [scrollable]="true"
      [rows]="100"
      scrollHeight="flex"
      [virtualScroll]="true"
      [virtualRowHeight]="34"
    >
    ...
    </p-table>
</div>
```

You can see this in action [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablevirtualscroll-demo-tnefqr?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Changing the scrollHeight to a fixed px height works no problem, but I really need this to fill whatever space is available.

Note that I need this behaving in v12 of primeng too.

Comment: your stackblitz link has some issue. can you please paste updated link

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about prime-p, but if it's neccessary indicate a fixed height I imagine you can use a variable

Or better use fromEvent(window,'resize') as observable

Declare in your component.ts

```
height$=fromEvent(window,'resize').pipe(
      startWith(null),
      map(_=>(window.innerHeight-50)+'px'))
```

(I substract 50px form the window.innerHeight)

And use

```
<p-table [scrollHeight]="height$|async" ...>
...
</p-table>
```

a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablevirtualscroll-demo-g1wsdh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

Seem like `primeng v.12.2.2` has missing some `CSS` part.

I added CSS in `style.css` and everything fixed like charm.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablevirtualscroll-demo-qn7ws3?file=src/styles.css)

Ref: Here is where I found the missing CSS part. (https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v12-lts/#/table/flexscroll)

Answer (score 1):

setting scrollHeight="flex" and adding height to parent is working fine with primeng v12.2.3 
[stackblitz with prime-ng 13](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablevirtualscroll-demo-rydt6b?file=src/app/app.component.html).
[stackblitz with prime-ng 12](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablevirtualscroll-demo-prct4v?file=src/app/app.component.html)

```
<div style="height: 200px;">
    <p-table
        [columns]="cols"
        [value]="virtualCars"
        [scrollable]="true"
        [rows]="100"
        scrollHeight="flex"
        [virtualScroll]="true"
        [virtualRowHeight]="34"
        [lazy]="true"
        (onLazyLoad)="loadCarsLazy($event)">
   </p-table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your `scrollHeight` to `flex` and just set your container `height` to the vertical window height (so it'll fill whatever space is available)

A solution, might be to set it to `calc(100vh - 150px)`, I've fixed [your stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablevirtualscroll-demo-8z8wwr?file=src%2Fstyles.css,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) and I think now it works as you expect:

```html
<!-- only relevant changes -->
<div style="height: calc(100vh - 150px)">
  ...
  <p-table scrollHeight="flex" ...>
      ...
  <p-table>
</div>
```